# Remove Red Destructive Button From ActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am trying to have an action sheet that pops up without a destructive button. If I simply try to remove the destructive button from the code below, I get an error: No visible interface for UIActionSheet. Does anyone know why this is happening? How can I remove the red destructive button? Thank you!

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive 
Button" otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];
```

Comment: Also note that this question has absolutely nothing to do with the IDE used, so you must not tag it with 'Xcode'.

Comment: Do not pass anything in 'destructiveButtonTitle', just set it to nil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Just pass `nil` as your `destructiveButtonTitle`**.

Just try with the below code:

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];
```

Comment: @Brandon You're in te serious need of learning Objective-C properly. You should not attempt creating complex application without even knowing the correct syntax.

Comment: haha indeed and @Brandon do not copy and paste without even knowing what it does! Learn it and then implement it :)

Answer (score 3):

> I get an error: No visible interface for UIActionSheet.

Care to read it further? The message is actually

> No visible interface for UIActionSheet declares the selector `initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`

Yes, because there's no initializer named that. You can't "remove" arguments like this (since it changes the name of the method, and **why would you expect nonexistent methods to exist?**)

You can simply pass `nil` as the destructive button title instead.